# How to multiple a number by 2 (double)present in a particular line number of a file, in Linux?

Tags: linux, awk, sed

**File_A**

```
Name: John Smith
Grade: 8
Institute: Baldwin
Number of entries: 125
State: Texas
```

**File_B**

```
Name: David Buck
Grade: 9
Institute: High Prime
Number of entries: 123
State: California
```

There are many such similar files in which the Number of entries (present at line number 4 in all files) has to doubled.

For File_A it should be 250 and for File_B 246.

How to do this for all files in Linux?(using sed or awk or any other commands)

**Tried commands:**

```
sed -i '4s/$2/$2*2/g' *.txt               (nothing happening from this)
awk "FNR==4 {sub($2,$2*2)}" *.txt         (getting syntax error)
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, please do mention your tried code in your question, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for all the answers.
With your help I was able to figure out simple solution by understanding and combining your answers.

Here it is (which worked in my environment):

**To display on terminal:**
`awk 'FNR==4 {sub($4,$4*2)} 1' File_A`

**To move to some file:**
`awk 'FNR==4 {sub($4,$4*2)} 1' File_A > temp_A`

**To perform changes inside file using inplace:**
`awk -i inplace 'FNR==4 {sub($4,$4*2)} 1' *.txt`

*`$4` being 4th parameter in the line;
`FNR==4` being the line number 4;
`1` at the end helps in printing everything*

Answer (score 5):

With your shown samples please try following `awk` code. Simple explanation would be look/search for string `/Number of entries:` and then multiply 2 into value of last field and save it within itself, then print lines by mentioning `1`.

```
awk '/Number of entries:/{$NF = ($NF * 2)} 1' File_A File_B
```

Run above command it will print output on screen, once you are Happy with output and want to save output into Input_file itself then you can try `awk`'s `-inplace` option(available in GNU `awk` 4.1+ version etc).

Also if your files extension is .txt then pass it to above `awk` program itself, `awk` can read multiple files itself.

Answer (score 3):

This might work for you (GNU sed and shell):

```
sed -Ei '4s/(.* )(.*)/echo "\1$((\2*2))"/e' file1 file2 filen
```

For line four of each file input, split the values into two back references and echo back those values using shell arithmetic to double the second value.

N.B. The `-i` option allows for address of line four to be found in all input files and those files to be amended in situ.

Answer (score 3):

Using `sed`

```
$ sed '/^Number of entries/s/[[:digit:]]\+/$((&*2))/;s/^/echo /e' input_file
```

Answer (score 2):

I want to explain why what you have tried failed, firstly

```
sed -i '4s/$2/$2*2/g' *.txt
```

`$` has not special meaning for GNU `sed`, that it is literal dollar sign, also GNU `sed` does not support arithmetic, so above command is: at 4th line replace dollar sign folowed by 2 using dollar sign followed by 2 followed by asterix followed by 2 and do so globally. You do not have literal `$2` at 4th line of file which is firstly rammed so nothing happens.

```
awk "FNR==4 {sub($2,$2*2)}" *.txt
```

You should not use `"` for enclosing awk command unless you want to summon mind-boggling bugs. You should use `'` in which case syntax error will be gone, however behavior will be not as desired. In order to do that your code might be reworked to

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=": "}FNR==4{$2*=2}{print}' *.txt
```

Observe that I specify `FS` and `OFS` to inform GNU `AWK` that field are separated and should be separated by `:`  rather than one-or-more whitespace characters (default) and do not use `sub` function (which is for working with regular expression), but rather simply increase 2 times operator (`*=2`) and I also `print` line, as without it output would be empty. If you want to know more about `FS` or `OFS` read [8 Powerful Awk Built-in Variables – FS, OFS, RS, ORS, NR, NF, FILENAME, FNR](https://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/01/8-powerful-awk-built-in-variables-fs-ofs-rs-ors-nr-nf-filename-fnr/)

Comment: or you can simplify it to `awk 'BEGIN { …  } FNR - 2^2 || ( $2 *= 2 )^_ '`

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> mawk 'BEGIN{ _+=_^=FS=OFS="Number of entries: " } NF<_ || $NF *=_'
> ```

```
Name: John Smith
Grade: 8
Institute: Baldwin
Number of entries: 250
State: Texas
Name: David Buck
Grade: 9
Institute: High Prime
Number of entries: 246
State: California
```